# How to use AngularJS to call out a specific function in a php script with $_GET?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, function, http

I am using AngularJS to access a PHP script but I only want to call out a specific function. In the app.js script below the updatePost and deletePost function are called by a button click. I am trying to call them by using get function but it's not working?

functions.php

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms1');

    if ($_GET['action'] === 'getPosts') {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        $posts = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $posts[] = $row;
        }
        echo $json_info = json_encode($posts);
    }

    elseif ($_GET['action'] === 'updatePost') {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_connecttents("php://input"));
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->id);
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->title);
        $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->description);
        $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->image);
        $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->category);
        $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->status);

        $query = "UPDATE posts SET title='$title',description='$description',image='$image',category='$category',status='$status' WHERE id=$id";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        echo true;
    }

    elseif ($_GET['action'] === 'deletePost') {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=$data->id";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        echo true;
    }

?>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('adminPanel', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])

.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'includes/main.php',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'})
  }])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    getPosts();
    function getPosts() {
        $http.post('functions.php').success(function(data) {
            $scope.posts = data;
        });
    }
    $scope.updatePost = function(post) {
        $http.post('functions.php?action=updatePost',{"id":post.id,"title":post.title,"description":post.description,"category":post.category,"status":post.status}).success(function(data) {
            if (data == true) {
                getPosts();
            }
        });
    }
    $scope.deletePost = function(post) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?")) {
            $http.post('functions.php?action=deletePost',{"id":post.id}).success(function(data) {
                if (data == true) {
                    getPosts();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you run the risk of creating severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). *

Comment: thanks for the tip, but do you know how I can solve my problem?

Comment: I don't know PHP, but it looks like you have a typo:  `file_get_connecttents` -- it is also strange to me that you're looking in `$_GET` for a `POST` request.  I'm not sure if that's normal PHP or not. . .

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo but I still can't call the if statements using angularjs?